# null value is not printed after json decode why?

Tags: php, json, decode

When json decode is working then it is removing the Null or 0 value from the array why ?

Below the example.

```
Array ( [address] => Array ( [address] => [postalCode] => [phoneNumber] => testing [city] => ) )
```

I am getting this one why it is not showing null in the empty values or 0.

```
$test = '{"address": {
            "address": null,
            "postalCode": null,
            "phoneNumber": "testing",
            "city": null
        }}';


  $test_decoded =json_decode($test, true);
 print_r($test_decoded);
```

It should be return null value or 0 value

Comment: No, null shouldn't be represented with 0. You can use `var_dump()` to see the actual type. If you use `print_r`, false will also be shown as empty, true will be 1.

Comment: @frz3993 I am using this decode into foreach and then i am getting empty value . It just a example which i am showing you using print_r

Comment: I don't know why it shows as empty, maybe that is what the people who wrote PHP define as human readable information. But the actual value is still null, if you use strict comparator `$test_decoded['address']['address'] === null` it will be  `true` and `$test_decoded['address']['address'] === ''` will be false

Comment: Is there any idea which parameter I need to use into getting the null value.

Comment: $val = $test_decoded['address']['address'] ?? 0;